# Call dart code from native plugin synchronously

Tags: flutter, dart, icloud, flutter-platform-channel

I know we can call `FlutterResult` to send data from native plugin to dart like this:

```swift
// swift func
public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
  result("send something to dart")
}
```

But I run into a more tricky situcation. I'm calling `NSFileCoordinator.coordinate`, I only have file access in callback function:

```swift
NSFileCoordinator().coordinate(readingItemAt: url, error: &error) { (url) in
  // you have access
}
```

I'm hoping I can call dart code synchronously to read the file so that I wouldn't lose file access.

```swift
NSFileCoordinator().coordinate(readingItemAt: url, error: &error) { (url) in
  // Call dart code to read the file and block the current thread!!!
}
```

Seems not possible.

Comment: No, that's not possible. One question is, what and why are you trying to coordinate? Could this be done elsewhere? Could you perform the read in native and pass the bytes to Dart?

Comment: @RichardHeap I'm downloading files in an iCloud folder (like a iCloud-based note app). I also tried `startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL`, there seems to be no reliable way to get notified when the download is completed (using `NSMetadataItem` and notifications). Yes, I ended up with copying the file to another tmp file. And use dart to read the tmp file. :D